# What is the best alternative to Google Reader?

Tags: 12.10, software-recommendation, google, rss

I enjoy using [Lightread](https://launchpad.net/lightread) in Ubuntu 12.10. The thing is Google Reader is being shutdown and Lightread is a client for Google Reader, so it's feed will be cut of.

What is the best alternative as a RSS reader for Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: have you ever tried Newsblur?

Comment: You can find a really nice list of different alternatives here http://www.replacereader.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If browser based, I am switching to Feedly. It will import your Google Reader account automatically. Google will help you find a suitable replacement.

EDIT; I have now settled on InoReader, far classier than Feedly, (actually has a working Chromium extension with unread count!) Also can subscribe to feeds via RSS Subscription Extension (by Google). Double lovely, indeed, super nice!

Comment: I hear feedly depends on google reader. If that is true, I think its not an option then since reader is shutting down

Comment: 'Update: Feedly has also said that they'll have a "seamless" transition method in place when Reader goes down.'

Comment: Feedly also has a nice Android and iPhone App

Comment: So far, it seems it's the best alternative. The only downside is that there's no off-line support.

Comment: You can only login to Feedly with your Google account...

Answer (score 8):

It's being overloaded with traffic, but look at [Newsblur](http://newsblur.com). The code is open and on Github, the site is designed in a freemium model.

Comment: The problem is there isn't a Ubuntu version for desktop :(

Answer (score 7):

At the moment I would recommend [Liferea](http://lzone.de/liferea/) due to the ease with which you can import your feeds from google reader and the aesthetics are closest to that of Lightread compared with other readers like RSSOwl for instance.

Shame google reader is disappearing. 
I hope Lightread might get a feature to work without google reader.

Comment: I installed Liferea, and it's great. The problem is that it does not have a Android app (for my phone and tablet). That leaves me without reading my RSS out of home :(

Comment: Nice, no-nonsense feed reader good enough to replace the good old, and dying, M2 from Opera.

Answer (score 4):

This site should help you decide:
http://www.replacereader.com/

Currently `Feedly` has more supporters on that site.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue indeed. **Liferea Feed Reader** seams to be a good alternative but I'll also give another try to **Yarssr**. Both are in the ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 2):

[Commafeed](https://www.commafeed.com/) and [Tiny Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org/) are also two free RSS readers.

Answer (score 1):

If importing isn't a big concern, consider Pulse ([pulse.me](https://www.pulse.me/)). It offers a Web UI plus Android and iOS apps.

Comment: The thing is that Lightread had an Ubuntu client (program for the ubuntu desktop) and GoogleReader had an Android app (for my tablet and cellphone). If Pulse doesn't have a Ubuntu client, then it isn't a perfect replacement.

Comment: @PabloViollier - I agree. One thing I keep hoping will happen is the ability to run Android apps on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best alternative is [Opera Browser](http://www.opera.com/computer/linux). It has a mail and rss reader integrated in the browser easily read to feed and open switch between rss, mail, surfing and other features in one app.

[image]

You could also try Thunderbirds - Evolution.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative could be [Stringer](https://github.com/swanson/stringer). Is a self-hosted RSS Reader that you could run in Heroku or any other server instance, so, as its creator says, `When BIG_FREE_READER shuts down, your instance of Stringer will still be kicking.`

Answer (score 0):

Check out Feedbro - an excellent feed reader (RSS, Atom, RDF) to replace Google Reader. Works as a standalone Chrome extension! Very fast, feature rich & easy to use.

Home page & link to Chrome Web Store at: http://nodetics.com/feedbro

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great post. I like feedly. Its very best in design and very easy to handle. There are many new readers are coming in market. Recently digg Started Its digg Reader which is a good start. [Here](http://www.diggbloggers.com/2013/07/10-google-reader-alternatives-that-will.html) are some alternatives to help you.

I belive Feedly is best and others such as newsblur/ pulse are also worth a try. If you are looking for Browser friendly then Aol reader , Tiny Tiny RSS , Feedbin , Yoleo is best options.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [The Old Reader](https://theoldreader.com/), which is very similar to Google Reader. It is browser based and allows to import your data from an other RSS reader and has an API for apps.